# が合わせて versus の合わせて

Tags: word-choice, particles

- ①この事故による死傷者は、女性3人、男性4人の合わせて7人ということになる。
- ②この事故による死傷者は、女性3人、男性4人が合わせて7人ということになる。

A Japanese friend of mine told me that ② is not wrong but ① is better than ②. Could any expert tell me why の is better than が in this sentence (and the interchangeability of が合わせる and の合わせる)?

Answer (score 2):

> the interchangeability of が合わせる and の合わせる

You don't seem to be parsing the sentence correctly, I'm afraid.

> この事故による死傷者は、**女性3人、男性4人の**（合わせて）**7人**ということになる。

The 合わせて is an adverbial phrase, meaning "in total". The の continues to 7人, not to 合わせて.

> 女性3人、男性4人**の**7人

The の is appositive. 「女性3人、男性4人」 is in apposition to 「7人」.

A few examples of appositive の:

> 「弟**の**次郎」"my brother Jiro"
>   「羊**の**ショーン」 "Shaun the Sheep"
>   「リンゴ1箱とミカン1箱**の**計2箱」"a box of apples and a box of oranges, two boxes in total"

For more on this, you may want to read:

- https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/62058/9831
- https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/21464/9831

Answer (score 1):

I think ② is wrong.
To clear the problem up, I change the details.
死傷者は、女性3人と男性4人の、合わせて7人だ。
So you can realize 合わせて is just a kind of adverb.
死傷者は、女性3人と男性4人の、7人だ。
Reading this sentence, you know that の is a part of adjective like の in 黒の服, 昔の話.
死傷者は、女性3人と男性4人が、7人だ。
I think this can't make sense though I can imagine what it means.